# Is it possible to recover my project after recovering it from a formatted hard-drive. The code encoding changed and I can't change it

Tags: java, spring-mvc, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I recently formatted my hard-drive while installing Linux. And I lost everything on my drive I then used EaseUs to recover my files including the project I was working on. Problem now is some of the files in my code has changed encoding. Does it mean ive permanently lost my project?

example of one of the code

EíèË‰Ó’
`F‰"@CËû’Ë÷ìS.`þØ—ƒËÇr‰Rù=x¸x?.ñ}Tt¸¼Eÿ£6DŸ« }Ù?Ý—²Mª}?ö§õkXÂKù/¥Œ`œ:‡õ]W“1Qsu}lun§æ:ýÐ{²Y¶vYÅÍXÊjÂË>Ÿ¬Sž¾äCÆ2ý2¡NÑ9õ”J^¾{ÃËÌÒ:§÷•ÖÞåŽªà•éN¯\?`X8@ ø|¬¸Jþ+“gÓ ÃÀe~•ÕõNãO‚XCÅpºÌä²§eÿ¿Uù¿’¯[Á|‘\Ujã) (åýK«&&?¶$ †=úü»ª›‰\
å%ÂZ¬ÏÏÿÖ7ÂõBP{¾÷I±(x¨I•—ª€ÙâùUûñœšB¬µ1¦ŠO†ð`›v[Ù³›.Ë†víæeË.Ù.öc‘ÊŠh±~Lb‘ÚY¯,u‰%­ÛcÒiÒB'    Ý}Š©xêKY²,N¯Ó>=Šì/ð÷së©<?‚LÂ‘ KËåž¿—_ÎÛ=—9½ˆžÈ“‹Á¾%Âñÿðó‚$ƒQ$|=…âHC¨Aãï—ÁT²wb¿go¨‹$>¬J+¾êÀ9@AÝÈªÈ]ZQÞÂZ¨¾Ù%´Yïª·ê¬àþd1 Eá¿1WËÇ¸×‡ìM„—ú+W3õ†@†%Bú$‰j —?m/Ú·±à¬¹TT¥Zª¯ZVªóIeô—¾’Þš»rÉýŠ{u— Pè»ÈYÈ uzü‰ŸyQÛ8?ƒú<øúå.¼¾§rÙ$Õ)dÑ©ñÜ  A8@/ð(.Âï¨fªªj8lP`‚£„¡ !÷š

Comment: I think it's not just an "encoding change" but complete garbage, which means you have to say goodbye to it. You can try other recovery solutions but since you have written to the disk (install) after deletion (format), you don't have much chance to get back your files.

Comment: This is heart breaking. Thank you juzraai let me work on the code again